# Axios.all in componentWillReceiveProps not called

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Using React and Redux, I need to wait for all my actions to be fulfilled in order to update the component state. Reading Axios docs I found axios.all to collect all my actions and wait for all of them to be resolved (basically I am calling an API n times to get info on n items). 
The issue is that the console.log inside the .then function of axios.all doesn't return anything at all, but actions are dispatched correctly.

```
if (this.props.evaluation && this.props.evaluation.topics) {
  var promises = []

  var array = this.props.evaluation.topics;
  var selectedArray = []
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    promises.push(this.props.fetchTopic(array[i]))
  }

  axios.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(response) {
      console.log('///////////////////////');
      console.log(response.value);
      console.log('///////////////////////');
    })
  });
}
```

**EDIT**: Here is my fetchTopic code

In my component:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchTopic: (id) => dispatch(fetchTopic(id)),
})
```

In my actions.js

```
export const fetchTopic = (id) => ({
  type: "FETCH_TOPIC",
  payload: axios.get(process.env.SERVICE_URL + '/topic/' + id, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'JWT ' + sessionStorage.jwt }})
})
```

Comment: Add `fetchTopic` code. Make sure it returns a promise.

Comment: Actions creators must return plain javascript objects, yours is returnign an axios call in the payload which wont work

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
export const fetchTopic = (id) => ({
  type: "FETCH_TOPIC",
  payload: axios.get(process.env.SERVICE_URL + '/topic/' + id, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'JWT ' + sessionStorage.jwt }})
})
```

to this

```
   export const fetchTopic = (id, cb) => {
     axios.get(process.env.SERVICE_URL + '/topic/' + id, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'JWT ' + sessionStorage.jwt }})
     .then((response) => {
       if (cb) cb({ type: "FETCH_TOPIC", payload:response })
     });
    }
```

And run

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  this.props.fetchTopic(array[i], (result) => {
    // get the result here
  })
}
```